# How to Write 404 Redirected .htaccess code?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I Have moved my site from asp to php.
I want to redirect my Old ULR which is

```
http://www.mysite.com/ABC/Home.aspx
```

to new URL

```
http://www.mysite.com
```

How to do that?? I came to know we can do this .htaccess file. but i don't know about its programing. can some body share a code with me? and where to place this code?? in Main .htaccess file or create a .htaccess file in my ABC folder??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Used following code in .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 /ABC/Home.aspx http://www.addictiveblogs.com/
Redirect 301 /ABC http://www.addictiveblogs.com/
```

and put this .htaccess file in my ABC folder. It works fine for me. Now Redirecting my All traffic http://www.addictiveblogs.com/ABC/Home.aspx and http://www.addictiveblogs.com/ABC/ to my Home Page.

Source: http://www.addictiveblogs.com/301-404-redirect-to-new-pages-through-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Check this link if your site on Apache server

http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

**Edit**

User this code in your .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: Above site is So Complex to use.